# AppCompatEditText doesnt show bullet symbol correctly

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-appcompat, androidx

I use `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText` view in my app for writing password. And I want to replace the real symbols by the bullet symbols. For this I use the next code. Here is the view

```
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        android:id="@+id/regPasswordEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:hint="@string/password"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/text_gray"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

And for replacing symbol by the bullet symbol I use:

```
  regPasswordEditText.transformationMethod = AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod()
```

and class:

```
public class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {

@Override
public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
    return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
}

private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
    private CharSequence mSource;

    PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
        mSource = source; // Store char sequence
    }

    public char charAt(int index) {
        return '•'; // This is the important part
    }

    public int length() {
        return mSource.length(); // Return default
    }

    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
    }
}
}
```

But when I write text into edittext field, I see the square bullets instead of the circle bullet, like on the image:

[image]

How to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
[TextInputEditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText)
or just EditText

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesnt work. I think, this is problem in androix

Answer (score 0):

Make changes to your charAt method as follows:

```
public char charAt(int index) {
    return 0x00002022; // This is the important part
}
```

By the way, try using a "Password" type of EditText - it will replace your password symbols with bullets automatically.